# GO Language ECDSA verify the valid signature to invalid

Tags: go, cryptography, digital-signature, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I coded the ECDSA functions in my C++ program. When I test my signature it works fine in my C++ ECDSA verify function, but not every test pass on the GO language.

Therefore, I tried to export my public key (from my C++) as hex string of buffer (33 bytes) to GO Language. Then, I use [ellipitc.UnmarshalCompressed](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/elliptic#UnmarshalCompressed) to retrieve my public key on GO program. Later, I found that the Unmarshal public key has different Y-coordinate when the public key is generated from the secret key using Scalar Multiplication. I have put the code below.

```
import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "os"
)    
func main() {

    /* UnmarshalCompressed public key from C++ buffer (hex string) */
    publicKeyBufferFromCplusplus, err := hex.DecodeString("02d36b0e521ca9a28cd6f2ddc56dc0973215702f6f67ed0670b9bc9a98c28d473b")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to convert hex to byte. ", err)
    }
    pk := new(ecdsa.PublicKey)
    pk.Curve = elliptic.P256()
    pk.X, pk.Y = elliptic.UnmarshalCompressed(elliptic.P256(), publicKeyBufferFromCplusplus[:])

    /* Generate the key pair in GO, using the private key (as decimal) from C++ */
    expect_sk := new(ecdsa.PrivateKey)
    expect_sk.D, _ = new(big.Int).SetString("50228957095953179898827503463423289296009712707225507368245266147079499081684", 10)
    expect_sk.PublicKey.Curve = elliptic.P256()
    expect_sk.PublicKey.X, expect_sk.PublicKey.Y = expect_sk.PublicKey.Curve.ScalarBaseMult(expect_sk.D.Bytes())
    expect_pk := expect_sk.PublicKey

    /* compare the two public keys, the X coordinate is the same, but Y is different */
    fmt.Printf("pk_x:\t\t%d\n", pk.X)
    fmt.Printf("expect pk_x:\t%d\n\n", expect_pk.X)
    fmt.Printf("pk_y:\t\t%d\n", pk.Y)
    fmt.Printf("expect pk_y:\t%d\n", expect_pk.Y)

}
```

Here's the result from the terminal

```
pk_x:           95627162525183504786576659676808415919520991299985517290103803735976207796027
expect pk_x:    95627162525183504786576659676808415919520991299985517290103803735976207796027

pk_y:           106312815215663533204607583749797836088594130128596587441436180287153537381066
expect pk_y:    9479273994692715558089863199609737441492013286693726754097451021713560472885
```

Please note that the difference is the Y-coordinate, where the X-coordinate is the same.

Comment: A cross-check with a Python code confirms the result of the Go code. The 2nd public key is valid for P-256 (aka secp256r1), but cannot verify the 3rd and 4th signature. It is possible that these signatures were generated with a private key unrelated to the public one, or have been corrupted in some way.

Comment: So the problem is most likely not caused by the Go code, which is thus not enough to answer the question. You should post the C++ code used to generate the 2nd key pair and the 3rd and 4th signature. And also the private key belonging to the 2nd public key (or if you can't post this, a *complete* set of new *test* data).

Comment: Right now it seems my y-coordinate of the public key is inconsistent with the value used to sign the signature.

Comment: Maybe, but your question lacks the information to check this. This would require the private key, and to find the cause, the C++ code for key generation and signing is needed.

Comment: @Topaco I have updated the question. It seems there's the difference between generating the public key from Scalar multiplication and UnmarshalCompress from the public key buffer.

Comment: The public key that is related to your private key has an odd y. Therefore, the leading marker byte in the compressed key must have the value 0x03 instead of 0x02. If you correct this (i.e. 0x03d36b0e521ca9a28cd6f2ddc56dc0973215702f6f67ed0670b9bc9a98c28d473b), the correct y value will be determined.

Comment: By the way, this is a new question by now and should have been posted as such. At least the new code should have been appended and the old one not overwritten. Subsequent readers will hardly be able to follow this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I found that my C++ Elliptic curve library has a bug when compressing (marshal) the public key (points) into [SEC 1, Version 2.0, Section 2.3.3](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) form. Some points have the first byte wrong (from odd to even, or even to odd).

```bash
1*G     GO buffer: 0x036b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296     C++ buffer: 0x026b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296
2*G     GO buffer: 0x037cf27b188d034f7e8a52380304b51ac3c08969e277f21b35a60b48fc47669978     C++ buffer: 0x037cf27b188d034f7e8a52380304b51ac3c08969e277f21b35a60b48fc47669978
3*G     GO buffer: 0x025ecbe4d1a6330a44c8f7ef951d4bf165e6c6b721efada985fb41661bc6e7fd6c     C++ buffer: 0x035ecbe4d1a6330a44c8f7ef951d4bf165e6c6b721efada985fb41661bc6e7fd6c
4*G     GO buffer: 0x02e2534a3532d08fbba02dde659ee62bd0031fe2db785596ef509302446b030852     C++ buffer: 0x02e2534a3532d08fbba02dde659ee62bd0031fe2db785596ef509302446b030852
5*G     GO buffer: 0x0251590b7a515140d2d784c85608668fdfef8c82fd1f5be52421554a0dc3d033ed     C++ buffer: 0x0251590b7a515140d2d784c85608668fdfef8c82fd1f5be52421554a0dc3d033ed
6*G     GO buffer: 0x02b01a172a76a4602c92d3242cb897dde3024c740debb215b4c6b0aae93c2291a9     C++ buffer: 0x03b01a172a76a4602c92d3242cb897dde3024c740debb215b4c6b0aae93c2291a9
7*G     GO buffer: 0x028e533b6fa0bf7b4625bb30667c01fb607ef9f8b8a80fef5b300628703187b2a3     C++ buffer: 0x038e533b6fa0bf7b4625bb30667c01fb607ef9f8b8a80fef5b300628703187b2a3
8*G     GO buffer: 0x0262d9779dbee9b0534042742d3ab54cadc1d238980fce97dbb4dd9dc1db6fb393     C++ buffer: 0x0362d9779dbee9b0534042742d3ab54cadc1d238980fce97dbb4dd9dc1db6fb393
9*G     GO buffer: 0x02ea68d7b6fedf0b71878938d51d71f8729e0acb8c2c6df8b3d79e8a4b90949ee0     C++ buffer: 0x02ea68d7b6fedf0b71878938d51d71f8729e0acb8c2c6df8b3d79e8a4b90949ee0
```

Therefore, some of the public keys (points) are exported as `{x,-y}`  instead of `{x,y}`

---

---

**Original**

The Elliptic Curve (EC) public key follows [the Standards for Efficient Cryptography (SEC), SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) in section 2.3.3 Elliptic-Curve-Point-to-Octet-String Conversion.

The public key in compressed form (as bytes) has the first byte as **0x02 if the y-coordinate is even**. Otherwise, **0x03 if the y-coordinate is odd**.

---

Mathematically, given only an x-coordinate

```
y^2 = x^3 + ax + b (mod p)
```

There are two solutions to the equation above, *(x, y)* and *(x, -y)* since y^2 = (-y)^2

In addition, -y is equal to (p - y) since it's a field of integers modulo prime **p**.

Since **p is prime** and p!=2, **p is odd**. Then, if **y** is odd, then **-y** (or **(p-y)**) is even, and vice versa.

---

The ECDSA verification algorithm does not require the y-coordinate of the public key since it requires only the x-coordinate of it. Therefore, when I check the signature tuple **{r,s}**, I will check it against with the public key which same x-coordinate, but different y-coordinate (flip from odd to even or vice-versa). I don't really know why GO Language ECDSA package allows only one of two y-coordinate value.

Here's my code sample below.
Let's say I have a compressed public key as a buffer `publicKeyBuffer[:]`

Then I can [Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/elliptic#UnmarshalCompressed) it to get the x-coordinate and y-coordinate

```golang
    pk := new(ecdsa.PublicKey)
    pk.Curve = elliptic.P256()    
    pk.X, pk.Y = elliptic.UnmarshalCompressed(elliptic.P256(), publicKeyBuffer[:])
```

We can check if the signature tuple {r,s} is valid or not

```
valid := ecdsa.Verify(pk, hash[:], r, s)
```

If the signature is invalid i.e. `valid == false` try changing the `pk.Y` value to its counterpart. You can do so in two simple ways.

The first way, you change the first byte of the public key buffer from either `0x02` to `0x03` or vice versa. You can achieve this by doing `XOR` first byte with `0x01` (simply 1).

```golang
    valid = ecdsa.Verify(pk, hash[:], r, s)

    /* The 1st way */
    if !valid {
        publicKeyBuffer[0] ^= 1 // change the y-coordinate by switching 0x02 to 0x03 (or vice versa) of public key buffer
        pk.X, pk.Y = elliptic.UnmarshalCompressed(elliptic.P256(), publicKeyBuffer[:])
        valid = ecdsa.Verify(pk, hash[:], r, s)
    }
    fmt.Println("signature verified:", valid)
```

In the 2nd way, we change the y-coordinate to its (p-y) value i.e., change it to (-y)

```golang
    valid = ecdsa.Verify(pk, hash[:], r, s)

    /* The 2nd way */
    if !valid {
        pk.Y = new(big.Int).Sub(pk.Curve.Params().P, pk.Y) // replace y-coordinate pk.Y with (-y), Note. (-y) is equal (p - y)
        valid = ecdsa.Verify(pk, hash[:], r, s)
    }
    fmt.Println("signature verified:", valid)
```

If the signature is still invalid, then it's not about the public key Unmarshal.

P.S. I don't know why the GO ECDSA Language does not allow the other y-coordinate value of the public key

Comment: Because, if `P=(x,y)` is your public key then `-P=(x,-y)` is not your public key. Also, when you use `-P` the verification must be terminated as an invalid signature.

Comment: *I don't really know why GO Language ECDSA package allows only one of two y-coordinate value:* I have the impression that you are assuming an ambiguity where none exists. When you create a signature, the public key used for verification is *unambiguous*. The public key can be specified in the uncompressed format 0x04|x|y or in the compressed format, m|x (with m = 0x02 for even y and 0x03 for odd y). Again, there is *no ambiguity*. 
So you never have to find the right y by trial and error.

Comment: This could only be necessary if the leading marker byte m is not set correctly (i.e. if the compressed key was determined wrongly). That was indeed the case in your posted example, s. [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721296/go-language-ecdsa-verify-the-valid-signature-to-invalid#comment130196649_73721296). Unfortunately, this is no longer clear from the current question, since you keep overwriting the content instead of appending the change (thus, s. the [history, rev 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cd511bf9-da9d-4105-9511-f08a83dc3126/view-source)).

Comment: Possibly there is a bug in the C++ code for the key export (e.g. when deriving the compressed key).

Comment: @Topaco There is a bug in my C++ elliptic curve library, which is used to marshal (compress) the key as you mention.