# crypto/elliptic: attempted operation on invalid point

Tags: go, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm using the `r` and `s` value after signing a payload to then decode it back to a signature.
First I convert the string values to a bigInt with

```
myBigInt := new(big.Int)
myBigInt.SetString(byteValue, 16)
```

Then I convert to the signature with

```
elliptic.Marshal(elliptic.P256(), &myBigIntR, &myBigIntS)
```

When I do this locally, I have no issues whatsoever. I am pushing this then to github and render.com picks it up. However on the server, i get:

I Receive:

```
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM  2023/03/15 17:36:31 http: panic serving : crypto/elliptic: attempted operation on invalid point
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM  goroutine 1252 [running]:
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM  net/http.(*conn).serve.func1()
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1854 +0xbf
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM  panic({0xc5ff40, 0xfaae70})
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:890 +0x263
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM  crypto/elliptic.panicIfNotOnCurve({0xfbc088?, 0x15d3950?}, 0x40?, 0xc000100400?)
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM      /usr/local/go/src/crypto/elliptic/elliptic.go:215 +0xa5
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM  crypto/elliptic.Marshal({0xfbc088, 0x15d3950}, 0x15d3950?, 0xc0002c2020?)
Mar 15 05:36:31 PM      /usr/local/go/src/crypto/elliptic/elliptic.go:105 +0x31
```

I cannot work out what could be different between the server version and a local version.
Has anyone come across this. Google didn't have much in the way of an obvious issue I could be making.

Using the sigR and sigS values:

```golang
    v2signature := new(refs.Signature)
    v2signature.SetScheme(refs.ECDSA_SHA512)

    signatureData := elliptic.Marshal(elliptic.P256(), &sigR, &sigS)
    v2signature.SetSign(signatureData)
    v2signature.SetKey(containerOwnerKey.Bytes()) //1. this should be the container owner

    var bearerV2 acl.BearerToken
    bearerToken.WriteToV2(&bearerV2)
    bearerV2.SetSignature(v2signature)
```

This is from an SDK that uses bearer tokens to access assets on a remote server.
I am creating a new signature using the two values r and s, with scheme `ECDSA_SHA512` and then attaching that to the bearer token

Comment: Do you have any local overrides in your `go.mod`?

Comment: Have you logged all input values on the server side and checked whether the inputs on the server actually match those on your local computer?

Comment: @JimB - no, no local overides.
Stephen - everything seems the same. I'm confused lol

Comment: @amlwwalker, there are only 2 possibilities, the code is different (which should not be possible with a module) or the input data is different. We can't verify either of those from the data given here.

Comment: Apart from the inconsistent behavior: A signature is not a valid EC point in general (r is the x-coordinate of a point, but s is just the signature proof). In the case of an invalid EC point a panic is raised by [`elliptic.Marshal()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.2:src/crypto/elliptic/elliptic.go;l=104).

Comment: So I just did a test. Service running locally, service on remote server. Same build, same hash.
Point local webpage form to the remote api. Get the error. Point local webpage form to localhost api, works perfectly. Same frontend, backends - hosted in different locations.
Although @Topaco please could you elaborate, maybe I've just been being lucky locally or something?
I found this answer - which is interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/73735011/1414721 although doesn't completely help

Comment: [`elliptic.Marshal()`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/elliptic#Marshal) converts a valid EC point to the uncompressed format. It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve for a signature, a format conversion of the signature to P1363 or ASN.1/DER?

Comment: @Topaco i have added some elaboration on how r and s are being used to the original post.
the refs library is github.com/nspcc-dev/neofs-api-go/v2/refs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sticking the whole lot in a docker image so that I could control versions of everything locally and remotely. This solved my issues. I suspect the cloud service was using some different Go version or something. Thanks for those who helped out!